Я не знаю в чём причина ошибки
from selenium import webdriver
import requests 
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import time
from selenium.webdriver.common.action_chains import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

def get_source_html(url):

  

  

service = Service(executable_path="C:/Users/seliv.DESKTOP-3PM6H4R/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python311/chromedriver.exe")
    #driver_service = Service(executable_path=ChromeDriverManager().install())
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)

driver.maximize_window()

try:
    driver.get(url=url)
    time.sleep(3)

   

 while True:
        find_element = driver.find_element(by=By.CLASS_NAME,     value="market_commodity_order_summary")



if driver.find_element(by=By.CLASS_NAME, value="market_commodity_orders_header_promote"):
        with open("lesson12/source-page.html", "w") as file:
            file.write(driver.page_source)
                       


    break
else:
        action = ActionChains(driver)
        action.move_to_element(find_element).perform()

except Exception as _ex:
    print(_ex)
finally:
    driver.close()
    driver.quit()

def main():
get_source_html(url="https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/Fracture%20Case")

if __name__ == "__main__":
 main()

всё что выше это код сайт не так его отображает
Я написал код для парсинга стим страници с кейсом и я хотел что бы мне выводилась начальная цена предмета но вместо этого я получил букет ошибок и я не понимаю что я не так сделал помогите решить их пожалуйста
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python tests\dfg.py", line 47, in <module>
    main()
  File "c:\python tests\dfg.py", line 43, in main
    get_source_html(url="https://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/730/Fracture%20Case")
  File "c:\python tests\dfg.py", line 16, in get_source_html
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=service)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
TypeError: WebDriver.__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'service'

это ошибки

отформатируйте код как полагается, со всеми требуемыми отступами, расставьте знаки препинания в вопросе. заодно, может, и от ошибки избавитесь.

Я конечно понимаю, что тут умные люди, но мне я просил не такой помощи. То ,что я не расставляю знаки препинания я знаю, но мне это никак не мешает. А если серьёзно то мне просто лень. Все отступы вроде верны потому что делал по подобию ролика с ютуба там у человека всё работало как надо у меня же нет (

Полагаю это из за того, что service не используется в новых версиях selenium,
попробуйте:
executable_path = "C:/Users/seliv.DESKTOP-3PM6H4R/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python311/chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=executable_path)
driver.maximize_window()


стало только хуже теперь показало больше ошибок

А можете показать новые ошибки? Плюс в вашем коде отступы неверно сделаны, возможно ошибки могут быть вызваны ими так как в питоне отступы играют важную роль, это не просто для красоты)

Пока вы написали мне я сидел и думал над этим же кодом в другом файле и потерял те ошибки(
Я в коде написал что бы скопированная информация выводилась в html файл в папку но после вашего сообщения и исправления файл перестал появляться вовсе хотя раньше он был но без информации.
С отступами я немного разобрался но думаю что не всё верно расставил.
Новая ошибка не очень похожа на ошибку но она явно что то пытается донести до меня но я упорно ничего не понимаю

Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":".market_content_block market_home_listing_table market_home_main_listing_table market_listing_table market_listing_table_active"}
(Session info: chrome=114.0.5735.199); For documentation on this error, please visit: https://www.selenium.dev/documentation/webdriver/troubleshooting/errors#no-such-element-exception
Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
GetHandleVerifier [0x00AAA813+48355]
(No symbol) [0x00A3C4B1]
(No symbol) [0x00945358]
(No symbol) [0x009709A5]
(

(No symbol) [0x00970B3B]
(No symbol) [0x0099E232]
(No symbol) [0x0098A784]
(No symbol) [0x0099C922]
(No symbol) [0x0098A536]
(No symbol) [0x009682DC]
(No symbol) [0x009693DD]
GetHandleVerifier [0x00D0AABD+2539405]
GetHandleVerifier [0x00D4A78F+2800735]
GetHandleVerifier [0x00D4456C+2775612]
GetHandleVerifier [0x00B351E0+616112]
(No symbol) [0x00A45F8C]
(No symbol) [0x00A42328]
(No symbol) [0x00A4240B]
(No symbol) [0x00A34FF7]
BaseThreadInitThunk [0x76BA00C9+25]
RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77087B4E+286]
RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x77087B1E+238]

извиняюсь что много всего просто ошибка была выведена в виде столбца который был на 600+ символов больше допущенного

@mixxxas ну у такой ошибки может быть несколько причин, 1-Элемент, который вы пытаетесь найти, еще не загрузился на странице. В таком случае вам нужно добавить ожидание например, с помощью WebDriverWait. 2-Селектор CSS неверный или элемент на странице имеет другую структуру. 3- Страница содержит фреймы (iframe). Если элемент находится внутри фрейма, вам нужно сначала переключиться на соответствующий фрейм с помощью метода switch_to.frame().

вопрос что если я ожидание сделаю с помощью time.sleep(10)?

@mixxxas не пробовал такого, но лучше использовать встроенные функии библиотеки, дабы избежать проблем

а где мне надо вставить WebDriverWait ?

у меня появилась новая проблема с тем что я пытался найти текст на сайте steam с помощью xpath но выдаёт ошибку
'NoneType' object has no attribute 'xpath'
и у  меня нету функции WebDriverWait

@mixxxas хм, странно, а какая версия библиотеки у вас? Может быть в самых последних версиях они снова поменяли что-то, если так, то надо в документацию смотреть или устанавливать определенную версию библиотеки

я использую pycharm или vs code в первом код нормально запускается во втором ошибка
я не много не понимаю что вы имеете ввиду под "библиотекой"

@mixxxas библиотек, это то что вы подключаете в начале, то есть по сути это уже готовый чужой код, from selenium import webdriver вот тут вы из библиотеки селениум устанавливаете класс вебдрайвер, а дальше в коде вы используете этот класс и его методы, но надо учитывать, что люди, которые делали библиотеку часто обновляют ее, поэтому старый код с использованием этой библиотеки может не работать. Если у вас в одном редакторе код работает, а в другом-нет, возможно у вас в виртуальных окружених установлены разные версии библиотеки, это надо проверять в редакторе

что на счёт ошибки  'NoneType' object has no attribute 'xpath'
